# Hoja que cree una tabla dinámica, en base a datos de otra hoja

Tags: excel, vba, tabla-dinámica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Como describí en la imágen, necesito un macro/código/hilo de funciones que me permitan crear una tabla dinámica, que tome los datos de la HOJA 1 (código del artículo y cantidad), y llene la tabla de la HOJA 2 con esos mismos valores.

Intenté ya con macros, pero lo único que me falla es que no se actualizan los valores para la tabla, es decir, cada vez que ejecutaba me llenaba la tabla de la HOJA 2 con los mismos valores.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿¡¿¡¿¡¿¡¿¡¿¡¿¡¿¡Y por qué no una tabla dinámica?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: No dices qué criterio sigues para llevarte datos de la HOJA1 a la HOJA2. Tampoco pones el código que has intentado hacer funcionar.

No entiendo por qué necesitas una tabla dinámica para lo que quieres hacer. Con recorrer la HOJA1 e ir insertando en la HOJA2 todas aquellas filas cuyo dato cantidad (Columna F) tiene valor. La tabla dinámica, para este caso, sobraría.

Comment: Creo que era la opción más efectiva, pero estoy abierto a propuestas! Perdón por herir sus sensibilidades, el código no vale la pena ponerlo porque lo hizo automáticamente la macro para crear la tabla. Pero tampoco me funcionaba.
A qué te refieres con recorrer una hoja e insertar en la otra? @dogwall

Comment: Por lo que me ha parecido entender necesitas pasar a la HOJA2 todos los datos que tengan un valor en las celdas de la columna F. La idea es recorrer la hoja1 de principio a fin con un bucle y, si encuentras una celda en la columna F con datos, insertas los valores que necesites en la HOJA2.¿No? La HOJA2 tiene pinta de ser un albarán o factura con los datos que se han anotado en la HOJA1.

Confirma el funcionamiento y vemos algo.

Comment: Hola! Exactamente lo que decís. Necesito recorrer la Hoja 1 recolectando datos, y pasarlos a la Hoja 2 (Lo de la columna G a la C y de la F a la D) Con Tabla dinámica ya lo tengo funcionando, pero como la Hoja 2 posteriormente se imprime, ésta tabla modifica el formato, y pierde su funcionalidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es una pequeña muestra. Con este código recorres la hoja y vas copiando los datos de una hoja a la otra:

```
Sub datos()

    Dim uf_1 As Long
    Dim uf_2 As Long
    Dim hoja1 As Worksheet
    Dim hoja2 As Worksheet
    
    'Hojas de trabajo
    Set hoja1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOJA1")
    Set hoja2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOJA2")
        
    'Ultima fila con datos en HOJA1
    uf_1 = hoja1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Recorro la HOJA1 desde la fila 5 hasta la última fila con datos
    For i = 5 To uf_1
            
        'Se la celda de la columna F tiene datos los traspaso a la hoja2
        If hoja1.Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" Then
            
            'Determino la última fila SIN datos en HOJA2
            uf_2 = hoja2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
            uf_2 = uf_2 + 1

            hoja2.Cells(uf_2, 3).Value = hoja1.Cells(i, 7).Value    'Artículo
            hoja2.Cells(uf_2, 4).Value = hoja1.Cells(i, 6).Value    'Cantidad
        
        End If
    
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Proceso finalizado!"

End Sub
```

Adáptalo si necesitas más columnas. También tendrás que montarte algo para vaciar la HOJA1 y la HOJA2.

Por supuesto este proceso puede hacerse de diferentes formas pero si no tienes práctica con VBA esta forma es más sencilla de comprender.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @dogwall , recien adapté tu código, debido a que la Hoja1, es la hoja 2 en mi libro, y la Hoja2 es la hoja 9. El código se recorre entero y tira el mensaje de Proceso Finalizado, pero los valores no se pasaron. Te comento que los datos deberia tomarlos del rango de celdas (F5:G66) de la Hoja 2, y transcribirlos al rango (A19:B37) de la Hoja 9.

Comment: Solo modifiqué esto:
`Sub datos()

    Dim uf_1 As Long
    Dim uf_2 As Long
    Dim Hoja2 As Worksheet
    Dim Hoja9 As Worksheet
    
    'Hojas de trabajo
    Set Hoja2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PRESUPUESTADOR")
    Set Hoja9 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REMITOII")`

@dogwall

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que los datos los está enviando al rango de celdas (C40:D44) @dogwall

Comment: Es que sin ver las hojas al completo es complicado sacar un código que funcione a la primera. Cuelga tu libro en algún sitio donde podamos descargarlo y ver cómo tienes montadas las hojas. Con una captura de pantalla es MUY complicado hacerse una idea global.

Comment: Si te comprendo, no sabía como responder con una imagen porque soy nuevo. Ya lo solucioné. Lo que estaba pasando era que al recorrer la columna de la segunda hoja (de abajo hacia arriba) se encontraba con otra información dentro del remito y por eso escribía en otro lado. Corrí dicha información y anduvo a la perfección. Muchisimas Gracias!